# How to change LetsEncrypt certbot domain?

Tags: django, unix, nginx, digital-ocean, certbot

I'm running my Django application on Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 16.04/Nginx/Gunicorn. I issued a (SSL?) certificate by running the following command:

```
sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path /home/user/app --installer nginx -d aaa.com -d www.aaa.com
```

however I now want to change my domain from `aaa.com` to `bbb.com`. How do I keep my certificate for my new domain? When I ran the command to issue the certificate, I assume it created various files such as the directory `.well-known` - and also added code in my Nginx conf. So do I simply run the same command again, with the new domain in?

```
sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path /home/user/app --installer nginx -d bbb.com -d www.bbb.com
```

or do I just change the current code and replace it with the new domain? E.g. my Nginx conf looks like this:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aaa.com/fullchain.pem; # 
managed by Ce$
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aaa.com/privkey.pem; # managed by $
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

I've already changed:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 172.128.67.232 bbb.com www.bbb.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/app;
    }
```

to my new domain `bbb.com`.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can not "move" a certificate that was issued for domain `aaa.com` and use it for domain `bbb.com`.

Cleanest way to handle this would be to remove all references to the old aaa.com cert and the old https setup and then run the `certbot ..` command to have domain `bbb.com` set up.